# What does 绝 means?

Tags: vocabulary

According to dictionary, it translated as "cut short" or "disappearing" or "vanishing". However, the phrase 太绝了 which I think it means "perfectly!".

I'd like to ask if 绝 can be use with meaning of "disappearing" object like "He disappear from the meeting"

Can anybody give mean an explanation on what 绝 really means?

Comment: bkrs：太绝了! Круто! http://translate.academic.ru/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE!/ru/en/ :Thunderbird! Holy cow! My ass! 绝 vb,adv,adj, see dictionaries, jukuu

Answer (score 2):

According to the [basic interpretation of 绝 in 汉典](http://www.zdic.net/z/21/js/7EDD.htm), there are 7 meanings.

> 1. 断
>      cut off; break off; discontinue; stop
> 2. 尽，穷尽
>      exhausted; die
> 3. 极，极端的
>      extreme
> 4. 独特的，少有的，没有人能赶上的
>      unique; superb; excellent; rare; no one can catch up
> 5. 一定的，肯定的
>      certain; absolute; for sure
> 6. 越过
>      cross; surpass
> 7. 旧体诗的一种体裁
>      A genre of classical Chinese poetry

If you mean "He left the meeting", it would be 他从会议上离开了. We seldom use 绝 in this case.

If we say 他从会议上绝迹了, it means he will never show up again.

绝迹 usually means a creature is completely extinct.